# Chrome extension switch between popup and panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to display the extension as a popup window or as a docked panel near the extension icon. Currently I'm displaying it as a popup window:

Manifest:

```
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
});

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.windows.create({
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
  type: "popup"
  }, function(win){
  vid = win.id;
  });
});
```

Instead how can I display as a docked panel if (){} ?

Comment: There are lots of extensions which have a browser action defined in the manifest (referencing a popup.html).  When clicked it shows a "panel" near the the extension icon. The "panel" dissappears if clicking somewhere else. I want to have both

Comment: As you see in the code, I have a page action which creates a window. I also want to have a page action which shows a popup (the one that dissappears if clicking outside it). This is where I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, I tested this. But if I set a default_popup then the windows.create in the pageAction.onClicked.addListener does not do anything anymore. The window isn't created. It just shows the default_popup. I want to show one or another in an if(){} condition. I've seen some extensions do that.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Use [chrome.pageAction.setPopup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-setPopup). Examples: [Controlling when the popup.html pops](//stackoverflow.com/a/6078974)

Comment: This works, by setting the setPopup to "" (nothing). Thank you.